# What would cause Flex/Flash preloader to hang over HTTPS in IE6?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, internet-explorer-6, https

I am deploying a Flash SWF which was built using Flex (3.2) / flexbuilder.  It is a single SWF which doesn't do any further data requests of its own.  It has some preloader code to display a progress bar when it is loading (it is approx. 650mb).

It works fine in almost all environments, but when deployed over HTTPS it fails to load - on IE6 only.  There is an error thrown by the preloader code which implies that a wrong value is being passed by the preloader event (nb. I am not a Flash expert!).

I found some documentation on Adobe which implies this sort of hanging may be caused by an invalid SSL certificate being used.  I suspect this may be the case (nb. I am no more a SSL expert than a Flash expert).  Are there any other options I should explore, or am I barking up a wrong tree in general?

FYI here's the bottom portion of the call stack

```
        at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
        at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
        at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()
        at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
        at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

Comment: Would be more interesting to get the upper part of the stack actually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by the use of "no-cache" headers in combination of HTTPS.
You can avoid this by removing them server-side (php, server-rewrites, etc.).

Adobe's note on the bug (2005):

http://kb.adobe.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=fdc7b5c&sliceId=2

Interesting test-suite done by Lessrain back in 2005 as well :

http://www.blog.lessrain.com/flash-loading-and-browser-cache-test-suite/

... But hey, are there really anybody out there still using IE6 ?